# how to install magento on customized sample database?

Tags: database, ce-1.9.0.1, upgrade, install, sample-data

Is There any way to install magento with some Copy of production database?
Exactly like installing Magento with [sample data](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html) 
i want to Customize my current database (in used with old magento version 1.9.0.1) and install current version on magento (1.9.2.1) on that Database (some Upgrade way)
my question is: how to customize database for this?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two ways: One easy and one more difficult (But better)

1) EASY: You can get your website all setup the way you want it with products, categories, CMS, static blocks, Configs. Then do a dump of the database. You can then create a custom import script that will restore that version of your site to a new site. All you will have to do is update your URL (If you change it)

2) BETTER: You can dump the same tables that are imported for the sample data AFTER you have done all your modifications. You can get these tables by looking at the tables the sample data imports. The sample data will drop and create all your tables, but will only insert data into some of the tables. The Install script will do the rest of the tables.